# Apache config not loading website correctly?

Tags: php, apache, debian, config

I have a file in sites-enabled called test

Inside test there is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin kyle@test.com
  ServerName test.com
  ServerAlias www.test.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test
  <Directory /var/www/test>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride None
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
  </Directory>
```

But when I'm going to this test.com (example), it's just loading to the default server IP, which has another website on it?

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please, I'm very confused to say the least.

Comment: other sites from sites-enabled works? may be you sites-enabled configs are not including in main config..

Comment: Yes, the main one using symfony works. And what do you mean by that?

Comment: did you restarted apache?

Answer (score 0):

You vhost config file will be end with `</VirtualHost>`, anyway you can test your apache2 configs with the command

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

Once you create the file on "sites-available" directory you need activate them with (for example):

```
a2ensite file_vhost.conf
```

then you need reload apache2 with

```
service apache2 reoad
```

The manual activation is create a symlink to "sites-enable" directory, for example:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/foo-domain.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enable/foo-domain.conf
```

and reload apache2